# ASPNET Core 3.x - Appending data to all API responses

Tags: asp.net-core

I've been googling for past 3 hours and I couldn't find anything helpful.
I'm trying to transform all my requests to a specific RESTful standard.

Right now, each and every controller returns data in this format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Test",
        "content": "Content Test",
        "userId": 1,
        "user": null,
        "categoryId": null,
        "category": null,
        "comments": null,
        "tags": null,
        "createdOn": null,
        "updatedOn": null
    }
]
```

What I want is to wrap all of these responses in a container, that also consists of metadata - as seen below:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusMessage": "success",
    "meta":
    {
        "count": 1,
        "total": 1,
        "pagination":
        {
            "page": 1,
            "pages": 1,
            "limit": 20
        },
        "filters": [],
        "sorters": []
    },
    "data":
    {
        [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Test",
                "content": "Content Test",
                "userId": 1,
                "user": null,
                "categoryId": null,
                "category": null,
                "comments": null,
                "tags": null,
                "createdOn": null,
                "updatedOn": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is the proper approach to just make a class called ResponseContainer and make all controllers return it? Because I feel like that's a viable solution.

Comment: Your suggested approach seems reasonable. It's the typical approach for handling pagination, HATEOAS links, etc.

Comment: Note that you are not really appending because the structure of the JSON changes after you add the metadata, I like your solution but if you were actually trying to append the response you could have used a custom middleware.

Comment: @ctyar True, I was looking for a more customisable solution.

My approach is to have: Resource and ResourceCollection, models I serialize on replies - since there's no point in having pagination or filtering data when returning a single resource.

I'm having a tough time inheriting from ActionResult thought.

Comment: My first thought is to create a base controller and add an overload for Ok() that adds the metadata you need to the result or inherit all your responses from a base class that calculates/adds the metadata

Comment: @ctyar Yeah, that's one way too - but that'd prevent me from being more precise with the output.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects, I used a generic class as response, such as `MyApiResponse<T>`. This class contains properties for meta data like the HttpStatusCode of the response, error messages, etc. They are set upon each response.

Within this class, I have a `List<T>` called `Data`.

Each API method returns `MyApiResponse<T>` where T is being the concrete data class. For instance, it could be `MyApiResponse<Weather>` where `Data` would store a `List<Weather`.

I'll definetly use this approach for my next API project as well.

Comment: This is literally what I've done.

I've also made ResourceCollection inherit IEnumerable so I can easily replace it being returned in controllers, without having to change IEnumerable<Model> to ResourceCollection<Model> in return type.

How do you deal with having to change all controllers to it thought and having to pass data in the constructor?

Comment: @JCode: What do you mean with *How do you deal with having to change all controllers to it thought and having to pass data in the constructor?* ?

Comment: Because if I use the wrapper model right? I have to change all generated controllers to return it rather than EF model.. and if I want each ResourceCollection response to contain count of all entries in the database, I have to also provide it with DbContext to run `db.Model.Count()` on.
I know the DbConext can be passed via Dependency Injection, but you still have to modify all controllers to return Resource/ResourceCollection.